# NA Each element of `...` must be a named string error when using matchmaker: match_df in R

Tags: r, string, data-cleaning

I have been using the cleaning dictionaries tool in the package matchmaker:match_df.

The code is as follows:

```
dat <-import("coded-data.csv")
dict <- import("dict.csv")
               
df <- match_df(dat,
                 dictionary = dict,
                 from = "options",
                 to = "values",
                 by = "grp")
```

However, I recently changed computers and now when I run the same code that worked before, I have been getting the following error on all variables:

"NA Each element of `...` must be a named string."

I am unsure on what this means or how to rectify it.

All of my variables are characters in both the dataframe and cleaning dictionary.

Comment: Where is this `import` function from? What does it return? It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.